# Using JMeter to record site interaction when a website is also using websockets

Tags: websocket, jmeter

To be clear, I'm not trying to capture the websocket output, but when I configure JMeter as a proxy to capture a website test case using record functionality the websocket requests do not get proxied correctly through JMeter.

This means the site doesn't function correctly and the tests can't progress.

Is there any way around this? (I have installed the websocket extensions in JMeter however they appear to be designed to interact with web sockets directly rather than accommodate this use case)

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think about is to not use JMeter recording at all, instead use some way to generate [HAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.har) file, and then convert it to JMeter script. There are few methods for both:

HAR file creation:

- Chrome/Firefox Developer Tools - Net tab has option to save network traffic in HAR format
- [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) recorded script can be converted to HAR (using its Export feature)

HAR to JMeter conversion: [this](http://seitenbau.github.io/har2JMeter/), [this](http://converter.blazemeter.com/), or [this](http://www.perftesting.co.uk/creating-jmeter-test-plans-with-fiddler/2013/03/01/) (if using Fiddler)

Comment: thanks, it is a shame that jmeter can't just proxy the websocket requests out of the box as I guess this isn't an unusual feature of newer sites these days.